# MPI Collective Reduce and Allreduce with MPI.MINLOC in mpi4py not working

Tags: python, numpy, mpi, mpi4py

I'm trying to execute this code with mpi4py:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

inp = numpy.random.rand(size)
senddata = inp[rank]
recvdata=comm.reduce(senddata,None,root=0,op=MPI.MINLOC)
print 'on task',rank,'reduce:    ',senddata,recvdata

recvdata=comm.allreduce(senddata,None,op=MPI.MINLOC)
print 'on task',rank,'allreduce: ',senddata,recvdata
```

With this command:

```
$ mpirun -np 4 python ./reduce_minlock.py
```

But instead of the expected result I'm getting this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./reduce_minlock.py", line 11, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./reduce_minlock.py", line 11, in <module>
    recvdata=comm.reduce(senddata,None,root=0,op=MPI.MINLOC)
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1298, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.reduce (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:109386)
TypeError: reduce() got multiple values for keyword argument 'op'
    recvdata=comm.reduce(senddata,None,root=0,op=MPI.MINLOC)
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1298, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.reduce (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:109386)
TypeError: reduce() got multiple values for keyword argument 'op'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./reduce_minlock.py", line 11, in <module>
    recvdata=comm.reduce(senddata,None,root=0,op=MPI.MINLOC)
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1298, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.reduce (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:109386)
TypeError: reduce() got multiple values for keyword argument 'op'
  File "./reduce_minlock.py", line 11, in <module>
    recvdata=comm.reduce(senddata,None,root=0,op=MPI.MINLOC)
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1298, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.reduce (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:109386)
TypeError: reduce() got multiple values for keyword argument 'op'
```

I got this code from this [Tutorial](https://info.gwdg.de/~ceulig/docs-dev/doku.php?id=en:services:application_services:high_performance_computing:mpi4py). What I don't understand is why there is a type error for reduce when I'm using the exact number of parameters. I wonder if MPI.MINLOC is supported by mpi4py. I did not find any warning about this operation on the documentation. These are my system configurations:

```
$ mpirun --version
mpirun (Open MPI) 1.10.3
Report bugs to http://www.open-mpi.org/community/help/
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
$ cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 24 (Twenty Four)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Reading more carefully into the error messages and trying to understand them could save a lot of potential trouble.

```
TypeError: reduce() got multiple values for keyword argument 'op'
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This is a purely Pythonic run-time error and has nothing to do with MPI per se. It should prompt you to look up the correct signature of `MPI.Comm.reduce()` first and only after checking with it state that the number of arguments is exact. And indeed, a look into [Comm.pyx](https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py/src/08fe8e8b6da4288252fe9f5e399c9406a5934a15/src/mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#Comm.pyx-1286) reveals that `reduce()` takes only three arguments (one required and two defaulted) besides the `self` reference:

```
def reduce(self, sendobj, op=SUM, int root=0):
```

You are providing two arguments as positional and two as name-value pairs. The second positional argument `None` and the second named one both provide values for `op`, therefore the type error. Similarly, one could check that `allreduce()` takes only two arguments and not three.

The conclusion is that the tutorial is wrong and probably based on an earlier version of `mpi4py` and the number of arguments you are passing to `reduce()` and `allreduce()` is actually not exact. You should drop the `None` argument from both calls.